# How to disable button double click on button

Tags: android

I have next button in one activity which takes you to the next activity and the same button is used their to go to next activity.

Here my problem is when I click twice on next in first activity it is taking me to the third activity.

Comment: call button.setEnabled(false); as soon as the first click happens. Later set it back to true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Preventing Double Click On A Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608720/android-preventing-double-click-on-a-button)

Comment: I have used button.setEnabled(false) and button.setClickable(false); after first click of the button. but no use.

Comment: Sounds like you have the same id on the buttons ? Could you post the xml layouts and two classes for us to look at?

Comment: Yes, its the same Button i am using  both places which included in xml