# Retaining focus on Edittext within OnFocusChanged Listener

Tags: java, android, focus, setfocus, imeoptions

I am trying to set up a system to validate user input, in this case, just checking that there is anything entered by the user.

I have a `Utility class` that checks that the `EditText` has data.

I am using an `OnFocusChangeListener` which then calls the method from the `Utility class`.

This is the code from the `activity`:

```
editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (Utility.checkInput(editText) == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter value!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // TODO....
                    // Retain focus - do not allow user to move on.
                    // This is where I am lost...

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code from the `Utility class`:

```
public class Utility {
    public static boolean checkInput(EditText editText) {
        if (editText.getText().length() != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //.../
```

1. Where I am stumped is how to retain focus if the check input returns false. I want to prevent the user from moving forward. I am sure there is a simple solution, but I have not found it.
2. I am also wondering if the `xml` `ime.Options` will affect this.
   Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is my xml:

```
<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLength="24"/>

<spinner ../

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:maxLength="12"/>
```

When I use:

```
if (!hasFocus) {
    if (Utility.checkInput(name) == false) {
        Toast.makeText(AddDriverUserActivity.this, "Enter value!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
         name.requestFocus();
      }
 }
```

The problem is, I am using action done (to hide the keyboard), as the user then selects from a spinner then proceeds to the next `EditText`. So the toast isn't showing until I touch the next edit text (phone) and the focus is then set on two edit texts:

[image]

When I reset:

`android:imeOptions="actionDone"` 
to `actionNext` it shows the toast and then proceeds to the next edittext, as shown in the screen shot, both are focused.

`Request focus` doesn't prevent it from moving from the edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [View.requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus())

```
// Retain focus - do not allow user to move on.
editText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to retaining `focus` within the `EditText` to validate input, but it is an elegant way to check for user input.

I add all my `EditText`s to an `array` and pass them to a method that loops through the array and checks each for input.

In my `Utility class`:

```
public static boolean checkAllInput(EditText[] editTexts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++) {
        if (editTexts[i].getText().length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the activity/fragment:

I add the EditTexts to an array:

```
final EditText[] editTexts = {arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, .../};
```

Then use the function in my `OnTouchListener` for the `button`.

```
addBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            hideKeyboard();
            disableButton(addBtn);
            if (Utility.checkAllInput(editTexts) == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter all fields",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                enableButton(addBtn);
            } else {
                // Do something ..
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I thought this might be helpful for others working their way through `android`.

As a side note, I have been disabling my buttons, to prevent repeated touches:
[Using countdown to set button enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491182/using-countdown-to-set-button-enabled)