# Avoid an item from Action Bar from being double clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, android-actionbar

I have designed an action bar for my Android app. In this action bar there's a button that launches a Dialog Activity used to configure my app's behavior. If I double click this button fast enough, I'm able to order the Dialog Activity to be launched twice before it actually appears, and then it appears duplicated and visually overlapped and I don't want this. I tried to create some sort of lock-down mechanism but it is not working because my Dialog Activity is launched only after all the code in my Main Activity calling method (onOptionsItemSelected) is executed. Is there a way to avoid this form happening?

My code is:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

//ensure only one element from the option menu is launched at once (if you double click fast you could launch two)

Log.e("test", "onOptionsItemSelected ");
if(optionItemAlreadySelected == false)
{
    optionItemAlreadySelected = true;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id ==  R.id.action_sound_mode) {
        //item.setVisible(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SoundConfigurationActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        optionItemAlreadySelected = false; //this code is executed before the activity is started!!!
        return true;
    }

}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Is there a way to know when the Dialog Activity has already being closed and lock the opportunity to open it once again until then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Preventing Double Click On A Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608720/android-preventing-double-click-on-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable to track the state of your `Dialog`. When you click the button you set `mDialogShown = true` to block any other show dialog requests. 
Now when the user presses Back button and the Dialog is closed onActivityResult is called. 
At this point your are sure that the Dialog was closed. 
I assumed your code is inside an Activity:

```
class MainActivity extend Activity {

    static final int SHOW_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
    static boolean mDialogShown = false;  // True if dialog is currently shown

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_sound_mode) {
            showDialog();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!mDialogShown) {
            mDialogShown = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SoundConfigurationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SHOW_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SHOW_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            mDialogShown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ActivityAsDialog

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin**

It's a screen(Activity, Fragment) based solution to avoid a double tap on menu action.

- Add below global variable to your activity/fragment containing onOptionsItemSelected function.

  ```
  private var previousClickTimeMillis = 0L
  ```
- Write below function anywhere in the project i.e Utils.

  ```
  fun singleSafeClick(
  previousClickTimeMillis: Long,
  block: (previousClickTimeMillis: Long) -> Unit) {
  val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
  if (currentTimeMillis < previousClickTimeMillis || currentTimeMillis >= previousClickTimeMillis + OnSingleClickListener.DELAY_MILLIS) {
   block(currentTimeMillis)
   }
  }
  ```
- Write your triggering code as below.

  ```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

   when (item.itemId) {
       R.id.action_delete -> {
           singleSafeClick(previousClickTimeMillis) { tappedTime ->
               previousClickTimeMillis = tappedTime
              // Write Yyur code here
           }
       }
   }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with flag, set var in fragment or activity

```
    private var dialogDisplayed = false
```

Make new fun

```
private fun showDialog() {
 if (!dialogDisplayed) {
        ...set code for opening dialog..
        dialog.show
        dialogDisplayed = true
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss()
        dialogDisplayed = false
        runBlocking {
            showDialog()
        }
    }
```

}