# How to disable a button for multiple click?

Tags: android, dialog, kotlin

I have a button that when click shows a dialog. But when you click the button quickly in multiple times, it will show 2 or more dialog on the screen. Depends on how many times you click the button before dialog shows. So I have to close each dialog many times...

I already used ***dialog.isShowing*** but it seems that it will ignore it when you click the button quickly in multiple times.

...So I want to click button at a time when dialog is closed.

```
private var mFlag = false

    fun myButton(view : View) {
        var tempDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()

        if (!mFlag) {
            myDialog.show()
            mFlag = true
        }

        if(dialog.isShowing){
           mFlag = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive, it is quiet confusing what are you trying to say. I want to help you on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16514644/3333848

Comment: I have button for showing n alertdialog... click it multiple times for less than 1 second and it will show many dialog...

Comment: thanks @ManthanPatel . how you put that answer section for just a link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have made public method for avoid double clicking issue on view.

Please check this method,

```
/***
 * To prevent from double clicking the row item and so prevents overlapping fragment.
 * **/
public static void avoidDoubleClicks(final View view) {
    final long DELAY_IN_MS = 900;
    if (!view.isClickable()) {
        return;
    }
    view.setClickable(false);
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setClickable(true);
        }
    }, DELAY_IN_MS);
}
```

You can use the method by following way,

```
  buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(String clickedText) {
                                                       Utils.avoidDoubleClicks(alertViewHolder.tv_alert);

    // Rest code here for onlick listener 

});
```

#### Or another way is,

```
private long lastClickTime = 0;

View.OnClickListener buttonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // preventing double, using threshold of 1000 ms
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1000){
            return;
        }

        lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great, but I don't want to use post delayed...for some reason - mem leak?!..

Comment: I have added another alternative for avoiding double click issue, please check the answer

Comment: yep, but I have less than 15 reps so it won't see publicly

Comment: worked for me, thanks but If I have background color for button after delay the ripple effect is showing on Material Button

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin(with adjustable delay):

```
class OnSingleClickListener(private val delay: Long) : View.OnClickListener {

  private var lastClickTime = 0L

  override fun onClick(view: View) {
      val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
      if (currentTime - lastClickTime < delay) { return }
      lastClickTime = currentTime
    }
  }

  fun View.setOnSingleClickListener(delay: Long = 500L) {
      setOnClickListener(OnSingleClickListener(delay))
  }
```

from [here](https://medium.com/@and_rey/singleclicklistener-debouncedclicklistener-for-android-app-1c55273fb1cf)