# How to prevent fast double clicking on a checkBox?

Tags: java, android

I have a weird issue with my **checkboxes** in **RecyclerView**.

When I **click once** on it everything works perfectly (move and change style) but when I **click twice** (enough fast) it performs some part of the code (just move it down and uncheck). I want to prevent it but I don't know how.

I tried the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16514644/10802597 but it makes it even worse (maybe I do it in a wrong way).

**Here is my code:**

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int currentPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if(isChecked){
                    FinalListItem finalItemBefore = finalListItems.get(currentPosition);
                    FinalListItem finalItemAfter = new FinalListItem(finalItemBefore.getName(), true);
                    finalListItems.remove(finalItemBefore);
                    finalListItems.add(finalItemAfter);
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listitem_green);
                    notifyItemMoved(currentPosition, getItemCount() - 1);

            }
            else{
                finalListItems.get(currentPosition).setChecked(false);
                notifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
            }

        }
    });
```

[image: Here is image which shows how i want to do it]

Comment: I'm not an android developer, but first idea came to my mind is that try to add checkbox double click event listener and just do nothing

Comment: Are you the javascript developer? :D idk if there is build in function for that but thanks for answer

Comment: this is not an issue while you can restore your miss-checking by next selection!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
     if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
                        return;
                    }
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

inside your click and it will prevent another click for 1 sec

but don't use it inside your checkbox method, from what I can see its adapter so set ID for the whole row and put this method on the row click.

Comment: I used that but where i have to put my code, to else statement? Or after this `mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();`?

Comment: you dont do else return; is your else

Comment: pretty much under                     mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
 do your checkbox code

Comment: so add holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 under  mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); and thats all you need